# Segmentation fault(core dumped) al inicializar una matriz

Tags: c, linux

Tengo este trozo de código:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  unsigned int N = atoi(argv[1]);   
  unsigned int fils = atoi(argv[2]);
  unsigned int cols = atoi(argv[3]);
  int i, j;
  struct timespec cgt1,cgt2; double ncgt;
  printf("%d / %d",fils,cols);


  double *v, *v_total, **M;
  v = (double*) malloc(N*sizeof(double));
  v_total = (double*) malloc(N*sizeof(double));
  M = (double**) malloc(fils*sizeof(double*));

  for(i=0;i<N;i++) M[i]= (double*) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));


  //Inicializador

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        v[i]=i;
        v_total[i]=0;
        M[i][j]=i*j;
    }
  }
//Operaciones

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
     v_total[i]+=M[i][j];
    }
   v_total[i]*=v[i];    
  }
```

El problema está en:`M[i][j]=i*j;`, quiero inicializar la matriz, pero al hacerlo me da un segmentation fault, y creo que tengo bien declarado el espacio de la matriz

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que no me salga?

Answer (score 1):

`M` se ha inicializado así:

```
M = (double**) malloc(fils*sizeof(double*));

for(i=0;i<N;i++) M[i]= (double*) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
```

Es decir, has creado una matriz de `fils x cols`. Sin embargo a la hora de inicializarla haces lo siguiente:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
  for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    v[i]=i;
    v_total[i]=0;
    M[i][j]=i*j;
  }
}
```

Es decir, tratas `M` como si fuese de tamaño `N x N`.

En el momento en el que `N` sea diferente a `fils` o a `cols` esa inicialización te producirá resultados extraños... y si además resulta que `N * N` es mayor que `fils * cols` entonces acabarás accediendo a memoria que no pertenece a `M` y ahí el Sistema Operativo puede matar tu proceso para proteger la memoria.

La solución es sencilla: Reemplaza `N` por `fils` y por `cols`:

```
for(i=0;i<fils;i++){
  for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
    v[i]=i;
    v_total[i]=0;
    M[i][j]=i*j;
  }
}
```